# Is there any risotto-style pasta recipe using eggs?

Tags: pasta

The Italians call cooking pasta “risotto style” when you make the sauce in the pasta’s cooking water and just let the starchy water reduce without ever draining it.

Is there any such recipe in which egg is added to the sauce?

Comment: Officially, I’m not aware of one…. But when I was in my 20s, I’ve stirred in a raw egg at the end when risotto wasn’t as creamy as I wanted.  (Part of the issue was not being able to get the correct back then).  You need the risotto to still be sufficiently liquid and hot enough for it to work well.

Comment: Oh, and you might be interested in Japanese egg rice:  https://www.seriouseats.com/tamago-kake-gohan-egg-rice-tkg-recipe-breakfast , which I assume would work for smaller pasta, too

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about that.

Cooking pasta "risotto way" is simply cooking pasta the same way we cook risotto, add liquid to the pasta (usually small shaped pasta) a ladle at a time until the pasta has absorbed most of the liquid.

IMO, using egg in those recipes might work if you add the egg at the very end of cooking to prevent the eggs from over cooking.

I can imagine a Carbonara risotto with folding the egg mixture just before serving.